# How to make a SwiftUI Foreach shows only items that has an extra parameter

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I am trying to show only users that have featuredact and cant seem to get it to work.
I can show all users but i only need to get show users that have featuredact

This is my Model

```
struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    let username: String
    let fullname: String
    var profileImageUrl: String
    let email: String
    var bio: String? //
    var location: String? //
    var website: String? //
    var verified: String?
    var featuredact: String?
}
```

This works to get all users

```
ForEach(peoplesViewModel.users) { users in
PeepsGridView(userInfo: users)
}
```

I tried using this

```
 ForEach(Array(peoplesViewModel.users), id:\.featuredact) {users in
                    FeaturedActsItemView(user: users)
                }
```

But with no luck.

Comment: Exclude what you don’t want to see in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be also done with filtered array

```
ForEach(peoplesViewModel.users.filter { $0.featuredact != nil }) { users in
   PeepsGridView(userInfo: users)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `id` parameter is for identifying structs, but since your `User` already conforms to `Identifiable`, you can omit it.

To only show the users that have a `featuredact`, you could just use an `if` block:

```
ForEach(peoplesViewModel.users) { user in

    /// unwrap `featuredact` to show the view only if it exists
    if let featuredact = user.featuredact {
        PeepsGridView(userInfo: user)
    }
}
```

Or maybe consider making a new array and filtering that.